# Android GC_concurrent pauses activity

Tags: android, garbage-collection

I love garbage collector, and it does it work good. But the problem is I have too many objects in my activity because there are too many Hashmaps and arraylists and other objects. So when I switch to other activity this happens.

```
12-04 01:02:17.119: D/dalvikvm(1124): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 46% free 26267K/48327K, paused 2ms+5ms
12-04 01:02:17.249: D/dalvikvm(1124): GC_CONCURRENT freed 8877K, 60% free 19436K/48327K, paused 2ms+5ms
12-04 01:02:17.359: D/dalvikvm(1124): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1593K, 59% free 19888K/48327K, paused 2ms+5ms
12-04 01:02:17.459: D/dalvikvm(1124): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1572K, 58% free 20363K/48327K, paused 2ms+5ms
12-04 01:02:17.559: D/ExchangeService(578): Received deviceId from Email app: null
12-04 01:02:17.559: D/ExchangeService(578): !!! deviceId unknown; stopping self and retrying
12-04 01:02:17.569: D/dalvikvm(1124): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1594K, 57% free 20816K/48327K, paused 2ms+6ms
12-04 01:02:17.679: D/dalvikvm(1124): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1582K, 56% free 21278K/48327K, paused 2ms+5ms
12-04 01:02:17.779: D/dalvikvm(1124): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1582K, 56% free 21741K/48327K, paused 2ms+5ms
12-04 01:02:17.889: D/dalvikvm(1124): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1582K, 55% free 22203K/48327K, paused 2ms+5ms
12-04 01:02:17.999: D/dalvikvm(1124): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1579K, 54% free 22669K/48327K, paused 2ms+6ms
12-04 01:02:18.109: D/dalvikvm(1124): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1585K, 53% free 23130K/48327K, paused 2ms+6ms
12-04 01:02:18.229: D/dalvikvm(1124): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1580K, 52% free 23592K/48327K, paused 2ms+6ms
12-04 01:02:18.339: D/dalvikvm(1124): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1584K, 51% free 24052K/48327K, paused 2ms+5ms
12-04 01:02:18.449: D/dalvikvm(1124): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1570K, 50% free 24527K/48327K, paused 2ms+5ms
12-04 01:02:18.569: D/dalvikvm(1124): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1563K, 49% free 25012K/48327K, paused 2ms+6ms
12-04 01:02:18.649: D/dalvikvm(1124): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 623K, 48% free 25189K/48327K, paused 39ms
12-04 01:02:18.659: I/dalvikvm-heap(1124): Grow heap (frag case) to 29.909MB for 5510676-byte allocation
12-04 01:02:18.719: D/dalvikvm(1124): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 37% free 30571K/48327K, paused 2ms+5ms
12-04 01:02:19.159: D/dalvikvm(1124): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1976K, 37% free 30571K/48327K, paused 2ms+5ms
12-04 01:02:19.599: D/dalvikvm(1124): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1972K, 37% free 30571K/48327K, paused 2ms+5ms
12-04 01:02:20.049: D/dalvikvm(1124): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1976K, 37% free 30571K/48327K, paused 2ms+6ms
```

So the problem is **Switching to other activity pauses the application for like 4 to 5 seconds** and it looks like the app is going to do **Unfortunately** and then ohter activity starts. **So what can I do to NOT pause the activity the app** 
What I have tried 
1. Starting Activity in async task. (Displaying the progressbar when GC does the above work)
but the progress dialog also pauses.
2. Do the same with handler and thread.

above things did not help.

So **How can I display a progress dialog when GC does its work and not pause the activity?** 
 I don't want to manually remove manually.

Comment: How about clearing all the hashmaps, lists, objects, whatever u hv before starting the new activity?

Comment: @Braj As I have mentioned I don't want to do it manually in my code. That is the last option.